# DataGridView Sort does not work

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 VB.NET

I have a DataGridView.DataSource set to a Collection of custom objects.   The columns use read only properties from the custom object for display, this dialog is for display only.  The properties all return String objects.  I set the columns all but 2 of them to sortmode automatic (the ones that are not set is a button or a checkbox).  Yet it does not sort.  I have googled around and most people use sql or binding sources but I am using a trivial vb collection.  Some say I should implement IComparable but isn't String already IComparable?

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanx

Bodger

Per a request here are some code snippets.

This method defines the columns in detail from columns I designed in the
designer.

The column names are called pSelected or pCustomer and corresponds with a
property by the same name that the column definition ties to.

```
Protected Sub UpdateDGVUS()
        If Not USColumnsInitted Then
            USColumnsInitted = True

            dgvUS.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            dgvUS.Columns.Clear()

            Dim iIdx As Integer

            iIdx = 0

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pSelected)
            dgvUS.Columns("pSelected").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pSelected").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pCustomer)
            dgvUS.Columns("pCustomer").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pCustomer").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pDetails)
            dgvUS.Columns("pDetails").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pDetails").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pSelectCustomerInvoice)
            dgvUS.Columns("pSelectCustomerInvoice").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pDate)
            dgvUS.Columns("pDate").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pDate").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pAmount)
            dgvUS.Columns("pAmount").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pAmount").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvUS.Columns("pAmount").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pName)
            dgvUS.Columns("pName").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pName").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pPayment)
            dgvUS.Columns("pPayment").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pPayment").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pCompany)
            dgvUS.Columns("pCompany").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pCompany").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pType)
            dgvUS.Columns("pType").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pType").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dgvUS.Columns.Insert(iIdx, Me.pDescription)
            dgvUS.Columns("pDescription").DisplayIndex = iIdx
            dgvUS.Columns("pDescription").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            iIdx = iIdx + 1

            dataUpdatedUS()
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is a snippet of the custom object that is in the collection

```
Public Class ItemXact01
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Company As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property RefNumber As String
    Public Property DownloadID As String
    Public Property Selected As Boolean
    Public Property RequestID As Integer

    ...

    Public ReadOnly Property pCompany As String
        Get
            pCompany = Company
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property pType As String
        Get
            pType = Type
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property pDescription As String
        Get
            pDescription = Description
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property pSelected As Boolean
        Get
            pSelected = Selected
        End Get
    End Property
```

...

The data is put into place with this code

```
    Private Sub dataUpdateDGV(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByRef myCollection As Collection)
        myMain.Log("dataUpdatedDGV: 001 :" & dgv.RowCount & ":" & myCollection.Count & ":")

' for some reason the not equal to does not show in the next line

        If dgv.RowCount  myCollection.Count Then
            myMain.Log("dataUpdatedDGV: 002")

            dgv.DataSource = Nothing
            If myCollection.Count > 0 Then
                myMain.Log("dataUpdatedDGV: 003")

                dgv.DataSource = myCollection
            End If
        End If

        myMain.Log("dataUpdatedDGV: 004")

        dgv.Invalidate()
        dgv.Update()
        dgv.Refresh()

        myMain.Log("dataUpdatedDGV: OUT")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to define the `DataGridView`.

Comment: I use the designer for the dialog.   It has a tab controller with some of the tabs containing datagridviews.  Here I can put some snippets I suppose:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can put a binding source between you collection and the datagridview and the binding source will provide a bunch of functionality. I think it allows you to sort as well. This is all just off the top of my head as I can't test it right now.

Comment: I found a SortableBindingList class out in the ether and it works.

Answer (score 5):

The key thing here is that the DataGridView isn't responsible for sorting;
the underlying data-source (i.e. .DataSource of the DataSource) is.

you could implement something like this SortableBindingList (for Windows.Forms)
http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html

Comment: You're right, but it must be said it is a disastrous design. How a grid is sorted is clearly a presentation matter and should be handled by the control. And frankly it's difficult to see why it would be hard to do, so long as the bound values in a column are the same type (usually the case) and implement IComparable (as all the basic datatypes do). One side-effect of this winforms approach is that you can't bind a list to multiple views, because the *datasource* tracks order and selected item and so on. Picture a view with lots of amounts and a dropdown list of currencies associated with each.

Comment: The sorting applied to a particular grid is in the DataGridView. The **method** for actual sorting is in the DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely for read-only purposes, and you don't need the user to be able to do dynamic sorting, then I'd recommend you sort the collection in your code prior to setting the datasource.

Example:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = null;
myCollection.Sort();
myDataGridView.DataSource = myCollection;
```

That could get you default sorting.
If you then need to implement dynamic sorting, 
I'd recommend you reuse your myCollection.Sort() method, such as making a new panel docked above the datagridview with buttons for sorting each column.  Link the click event in those buttons to your .Sort() method, and add a parameter to the method to know by which column to sort.

It's a little bit of work, but I think you'll have more luck implementing a custom sorting scenario than getting your Microsoft components to bend to your will.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't need it custom sorted, I just want it sorted by the column selected.  Nothing happens when I click on the column header.