# Unable to sort datagridview 

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, bindingsource

Hello i cannot sort alphabetical my datagridview

this is how i fill my grid :

```
 bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = db.GetProducts.ToList();
                dgvInventory.DataSource = bs;
```

and this is how i try to sort my grid :

```
     private void toolStripButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.Sort = "ID DESC, Name ASC";
        dgvInventory.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

And when i pressing button nothing happens
This two columns is exsist in data grid

and this is screen :

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.sort.aspx

> To support sorting, the underlying list must implement the
>   IBindingList or IBindingListView interfaces. This capability can be
>   queried through the SupportsSorting property. Multicolumn sorting is
>   available when the SupportsAdvancedSorting property is true.

You're calling the `ToList()` extension method which is going to return you a `List<Product>` which is not going to support either of those interfaces and hence won't be sortable.

Comment: hah thanks everybody for replay. I prefare easy way so i used linq to sql order by :D

Answer (score 1):

When You have custom objects, You have to implement SortableBindingList. Do a search on the Internet for this. The reason for such behaviour is that underlying source is responsible for sorting, not DataGridView.

Also, the same question here: [DataGridView Sort does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137635/datagridview-sort-does-not-work)